# event:inbound-channel-adapter with payload-expression not able to resolve bean

Tags: events, spring-integration

I'm attempting to use the event:inbound-channel-adapter as an ApplicationEventListener to capture the ContextRefreshedEvent so I can dynamically start a file:inbound-channel-adapter like:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" auto-startup="false"
    directory="${input.location}" channel="fileInChannel">
    <integration:poller ref="filesInPoller" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<event:inbound-channel-adapter id='appStarter' channel="nullChannel"                                    
                  error-channel="errorChannel" 
                  event-types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent"
                  payload-expression="@filesIn.start()"/>
```

But I get the following error indicating the sPel payload-expression cannot find the `filesIn` bean:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'filesIn'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.BeanReference.getValueInternal(BeanReference.java:45)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:49)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:72)
at org.springframework.integration.event.inbound.ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer.sendEventAsMessage(ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer.java:113)
at org.springframework.integration.event.inbound.ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
```

Am I correct in believing that the `file:inbound-channel-adapter` is able to be started in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Spring Integration are you using? The ability to reference a bean `@filesIn` was added to this adapter in 3.0.

If you are using 2.2 or below, upgrade to the current release (or at least 3.0.4).

In any case, you can't just send that command to `nullChannel`, it will evaluate to `null` and you can't have a `null` payload; you'll have to send `'@filesIn.start()'` to a `<control-bus/>`.

EDIT:

Or,  "`@filesIn.start() == null ? 'foo' : 'bar'`" will send  `foo` to the `nullChannel`.

Comment: Thanks, I am using an older version 2.2 and will upgrade. As far as the null channel,  isn't the SpEL payload-expression evaluated anyway, regardless of going to a null channel? And I thought this should start the filesIn adapter/polling.

Comment: Doh - of course; you are right; but it will fail because you can't create a payload with a `null` value, which is what we'll try to send to `nullChannel`. So you should use `payload-expression="'@filesIn.start()'"` (note the `'`s) and send that to the `<control-bus/>`.

Comment: This will work: `"@filesIn.start() == null ? 'foo' : 'bar'"` will send 
`foo` to the `nullChannel`.

Comment: Great; in that case, it's customary to accept the answer; thanks.